# Is there a way to have user-made functions give Intellisense warnings in code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm writing a function-- to tl;dr-- that appends values to a provided list. The provided list is *intended* to be empty, but can be given an already populated list and the values will simply be added to the end, no error.

I'm wondering if there's a way to give the user that **little yellow warning squiggly** if they provide a populated list.

I tried `import warnings` but that package prints an entirely new red line in the console, and only after compilation

Comment: Define a type variable for an empty list, and use that as the type annotation for the parameter.

Comment: @PM77-1 Who else would be using Intellisense and see warnings about calling the function incorrectly?

Comment: It seems like this code should just return a populated list instead requesting one from the user to populate. If you have an existing list that you want to fill, you could just have the function return a list, then reassign or unpack the populated list into the target list.

Comment: I worry that the reasoning about why you'd want to do this is an issue - if it's an acceptable thing to that they can pass a populated list, you shouldn't give them a warning. The function clearly isn't concerned with what is in the list, so shouldn't therefore be aware of any issues appending to it might cause.

If it's unacceptable to take a populated list, then your function shouldn't take it as an argument. You can initialise an empty list inside your function, and if the user then decides they want to extend a list they already have with the result, they can.
`lista.extends(listb)` 